# Android layout editor devices not holding their place for each different layout

Tags: android, graphical-layout-editor

I am trying to design different layouts for different screen sizes. I have created layout files for sw240dp, and I am now trying to design layouts for sw480dp. My problem involves the list of devices in the layout editor. I am trying to select a 3.7 inch device to design on, but the software keeps jumping over to the sw240dp layout file every time I select the 3.7 inch device for sw480dp. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Is there something wrong with my eclipse software, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What resolution and density are you selecting for the emulated device? The DP is determined by the density and resolution. So for 480 DP, here is the mapping from density to required pixel resolution:

```
MDPI (160) : 480px
HDPI (240) : 720px
XHDPI(320) : 960px
```

So if you're picking a 3.7" 480x800 device at HDPI, that's not going to fall into the `sw480dp` bucket. You'd need to create it as an MDPI device (i.e. density of 160).

Comment: I'm a little confused by your information, and I think I'm really misunderstanding how creating alternate resources works. The device definitions for 4.2 show numbers like 3.3 inch WQVGA (240 x 400 Normal ldpi screen) 3.7inch WVGA (480 x 800 Normal hdpi screen). This is what I'm going by when creating a new layout file using sw<N>dp for each different screen size. Are these not the correct numbers to use?

Comment: No, the `sw` qualifiers should be used only when you have a layout that will not fit in a smaller container. Typically the `sw` qualifier is only used to differentiate between phone, 7" tablet, and 10" tablet layouts (7" tablets == `sw600dp`, 10" tablets == `sw720dp`). For different size phone screens, you really shouldn't have to worry about making different layouts unless your layout just *requires* a certain amount of DP width, in which case you should use the `w` qualifier, e.g.(`w400dp` if you need 400 DP of width for the layout to function correctly)

Comment: Really? So, do I still need to create the following layouts: layout small, layout-normal, layout large, which are the screens I want to support? Or will my default layouts be automatically scaled to fit each one of the screens from 2.7inches up to, and including, 5.4 inches?

Comment: The second: Anything in the `layout` folder will be used for EVERY screen unless some more specific layout is available (e.g. `layout-land` and you're in landscape mode). By default, you only need *one* layout file. The only time you need to add more is if there's a specific case that needs to be handled, such as a tablet layout or a landscape layout. So no, you most likely don't need your small/normal/large specific layouts.

Comment: Well damn! I've been wasting all this time trying to construct different layouts for all the different screen sizes, and it's not even required. It's all good though; if we don't make mistakes, we never learn! Thanks for the info kcoppock, you are the man!

Comment: No problem. :) I see it all the time; a lot of people seem to get that impression, but yeah, if you're able to make an adaptable layout you should only have to make one layout. (more only if you want special tablet layouts)